# Do all active Esperanto-speakers use the Internet?

Tags: esperanto-speakers

Esperanto is a good tool for international communication. The Internet facilitates international communication with the help of e-mails and social media. Is there a significant amount of active Esperanto-speakers that do not use the Internet, and only use Esperanto in local clubs or in postcards?

Answer (score 9):

There are many elder Esperantists who don't use the Internet. At the *Universala Kongreso* I discussed with some people about Esperanto radio stations and mentioned podcasts. And they were like, if it's only on the net (and not e.g. shortwave) it's not real.

Comment: Elders probably have so much information and experience to share, but I feel we live in different worlds. If they don't use the internet, and if I never go to a flesh-and-blood meetup or contact them by snail mail, we'll never meet. Some people never will go to a physical meetup, for lack of time, money, or desire--and somewhere between those reasons I might be one of those people. Almost all of my Esperanto use is exclusively online. It's a strange feeling that there is such a big rift in the community demarcated mostly by age (and factors mentioned in Enrique's answer).

Answer (score 5):

There are many reasons not to use the Internet:

You cannot afford a computer. Even if you have a computer, 
you cannot afford the connection. There is no Internet in the 
area where you live. All of this can happen in any country.

Some people in Africa save as much as they can to pay for 
one hour at the cyber-cafe. One of them once told me that she 
have to pedal her bike about one hour (each way) to reach the 
cyber-cafe.

There are some Esperanto speakers in USA, Europe, and some 
other countries who send books and other items (paper, 
pencils) to people that aren't connected to the web.

By the way, next year I will be 80 and I use the Internet, and 
have a vast web site in 3 languages at:

```
http://esperantofre.com/edu/eepag.htm
```

Comment: Good point about computer/internet access. I have had similar conversations with Esperanto speakers from several African countries who I've emailed and chatted with, and who wanted to use the post to exchange things rather than relying on email.

Answer (score 3):

In France I've been in some local clubs where almost all Esperantists where elders who didn't use internet (with some exception).